# How to add new peer to private quorum network?

Tags: go-ethereum, quorum, peers

I have created a network using raft consensus using quorum-wizard. I have created another node on a vm using [this tutorial](https://docs.goquorum.consensys.net/en/20.10.0/Tutorials/Creating-A-Network-From-Scratch/).
I want to attach the single node to the network. for that I have followed [this tutorial](https://docs.goquorum.consensys.net/en/stable/HowTo/Use/adding_nodes/#raft).
But I'm always getting

```
rafthttp: failed to find member 3 in cluster 1000
rafthttp: failed to find member 2 in cluster 1000
rafthttp: failed to find member 1 in cluster 1000
```

and logs of quorum network shows this error

```
rafthttp: peer 4 became active
rafthttp: failed to dial 4 on stream MsgApp v2 (peer 4 failed to find local node 2)
rafthttp: peer 4 became inactive (message send to peer failed)
```

How to add new peer to the quorum network?

Answer (score 1):

As the new node is running from within a VM, this issue is most probably a network issue that's why the nodes are not able to communicate with each other. To double check that maybe use `nc` or `telnet` commands.